# EF Core entity configuration not applied in OnModelCreating

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a simple (at the moment) context which uses some base classes like this:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TranslatableEntityBase : EntityBase
{
    public string TranslationKey { get; set; }
    public TranslatableEntityBase(string translationKey) : base()
    {
        TranslationKey = translationKey;
    }
}

public class Country : TranslatableEntityBase
{
    public Country(string name, string code, string translationKey) 
    : base(translationKey)
    {
        Name = name;
        Code = code;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

The configurations also have base classes like this:

```
public abstract class EntityBaseConfiguration<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {

    }
}

public abstract class TranslatableEntityBaseConfiguration<T> : EntityBaseConfiguration<T> where T : TranslatableEntityBase
{
    // Hide parent method to provide overridable one to children
    public new virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.Property(e => e.TranslationKey)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}

public class CountryConfiguration : TranslatableEntityBaseConfiguration<Country>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Country> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.Property(c => c.Name)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasMaxLength(255);

        builder.Property(c => c.Code)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasMaxLength(3);
    }
}
```

And my context is defined this way:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}
```

When I run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration`, it creates the migration however the configuration of the entity is not applied (no max length or required).

I already tried using `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CountryConfiguration());` directly but with the same results.

What am I missing ?  Is it because of the inheritance ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it.

I just needed to make `TranslatableEntityBaseConfiguration<T>` inherit `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`

```
public abstract class TranslatableEntityBaseConfiguration<T> : EntityBaseConfiguration<T>, IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : TranslatableEntityBase
{
    // Hide parent method to provide overridable one to children
    public new virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.Property(e => e.TranslationKey)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

I don't really know why...

EDIT:
I found another cleaner way to do it, by removing `new virtual` from this class, and using `override` instead.  Which doesn't prevent me to override in the final class (which I naively thought)